# Multicolor text in TreeView (Embarcadero RAD studio)

Tags: c++, treeview, c++builder

I am writing a piece of software in C++ RAD studio 2010 and got a question about TreeView.
Is it possible to use multicolor text in a TTreeView component? I could not find a easy way but to implement custom drawing which seems to be weird nowadays. Are there any straight-forward ways or maybe additional components that can do it for me?

**UPDATE**

Ended up doing it with custom drawing.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::TreeView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(TCustomTreeView *Sender, TTreeNode *Node,
    TCustomDrawState State, TCustomDrawStage Stage, bool &PaintImages,
    bool &DefaultDraw)
if (Stage == cdPostPaint)
  {
 TRect rect(Node->DisplayRect(true));
 String redText = "redtext";
 String greenText = " greentext";
 Sender->Canvas->Font->Color = clRed;
 Sender->Canvas->Refresh();
 Sender->Canvas->TextOut(rect.Left, rect.Top, redText);

 rect.Left += Sender->Canvas->TextWidth(redText);

 Sender->Canvas->Font->Color = clGreen;
 Sender->Canvas->Refresh();
 Sender->Canvas->TextOut(rect.Left, rect.Top, greenText);

 rect.Left += Sender->Canvas->TextWidth(greenText);
  }
```

It was important to use *Refresh* so that the method works.

Also, after having realized that I needed multiline text to output I switched to VirtualTreeView component from [soft-gems](http://www.soft-gems.net/)

Comment: I have never had to use TCanvas::Refresh() inside a custom-draw handler.  Changing the Font multiple times has always worked fine for me without any extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom drawing is the only way.  There is nothing weird about that.  Many controls support custom drawing.